# Display Ninja Form submited data to wordpress page post

Tags: wordpress, data-processing, ninja-forms

I want to display ninja form submitted data to to my WordPress blog post (Page). Please suggest any way to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too broad, Show what you have tried otherwise your question will closed soon.

Comment: I just want to display ninja contact form data to my post

Comment: Again, read my previous comment. Show us what you have tried so far. No one will write code for you.

Comment: never tried yet because i don't know how to do and also fiind nothing on google.I am new in a world of wordpress. I just find how to add form on wordpress site. But can't find how to display that data to blog post in table format